# C# Shortening names in String/List

Tags: c#, string, list, parsing

For the purposes of filling out an axis on a graph, i need to limit the size of my  input. You supply the graph with a string, with each category separated by a comma in the string. The problem is, if the graph is rendered at a certain size the lettering starts to overlap. My string is a list of names, such as "John Smith, Steve Potatoes, Iron Man".

Id like shorten it to "J Smith, S Potatoes, I Man" dynamically. These names are also in a string list as well so i could work with that too. Any feedback on the best way to do that would be appreciated!

Comment: I plot these labels in a 45 degree angle...

Comment: What if the abbreviation is still too long? What have you tried?

Comment: "Manoj Night Shyamalan", becoming "M Night Shyamalan" will still be too long I guess?

Comment: Have you considered inserting line breaks?

Comment: It's not, i have it hard coded currently that way and its fine.

Comment: `abbr = name[0] + name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf(' '));`

Comment: If its hard coded, have some kind of `{full = "bob smith", short="B SMTH" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abbreviate the first word of each name...  Split the name into its parts using `.Split()` and then `.Substring()` to abbreviate how you like, e.g.

```
string name = "John Smith";

string[] nameParts = name.Split(' ');

nameParts[0] = nameParts[0].Substring(0, 1);

string abbrName = String.Join(" ", nameParts);

Console.WriteLine(abbrName);
```

Comment: will work for my circumstances, all the answers were helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Regex to replace your string for your purposes:

```
^([A-Z]).*?\s(.*?)$
```

And use it like this:

```
var name = "John Smith";
var pattern = @"^([A-Z]).*?\s(.*?)$";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(name, pattern, "$1 $2"); //Output = J Smith
```

I'm assuming you only have a first- and a last name for your cases. To apply the Regex to your list simply use a foreach loop:

```
var pattern = @"^([A-Z]).*?\s(.*?)$";
var shortenedList = new List<string>();
foreach (var name in stringList)
{
   shortenedList.Add(Regex.Replace(name, pattern, "$1 $2"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you should split your names list by comma (','), and you get a list as "Name Surname"
then split each list item with whitespace (' '), then , get first item's substring (0,1) + "." and all of the second item. And you have Names as "J. Smith"